# Simple Wikidata SPARQL query for cities, countries, and country property times out

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to fetch a sample of big cities (`Q1549591`) along with their country, and the countries' 3166-1 alpha-3 codes (`P298`). This simple query works as expected without the ISO codes, but when I add that part the query times out. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
SELECT ?cityLabel ?countryLabel ?iso
WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q1549591 .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?country wdt:P297 ?iso .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: https://w.wiki/DpU

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Could you explain why that snippet is needed in this example?

Comment: https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints, https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Explain.

Comment: the answer for why is simply that the query optimizer tries to estimate the one single query plan that is supposed to work best. Clearly, this is not always the case, with query hints you can help (or even disable) the query optimizer of the Blazegraph backend.